# Can I configure notification period of webapps?

Tags: 12.10, webapps

Webapps set the communication icon on blue when there are new tweets, messages, etc.

Is there a way to configure every how many minutes this is refreshed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### For Webapps

There is no easy GUI configuration to do this.

To set some the refresh delay you need to edit the file  **Twitter.user.js** located under  `/usr/share/unity-webapps/userscripts/unity-webapps-twitter`

Look for function : `function messagingIndicatorSetup() {` and introduce the time delay in it.

You can use

```
setInterval()
```

or

```
setTimeout()
```

to set the time delay

### For Gwibber

Open dash and search for "Broadcast Preferences" and open it.

and the bottom of the window you will find **Update**

**Minutes between refresh:** change it to desired refresh time.

[image]

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong. but i think this applies to gwibber, not webapps.

Comment: @dwaynemac You are right. Webapps twitter settings is different from gwibber though the both appear on messaging menu. Check the updated answer.