# How to check if Unity web apps for gmail (or other) is installed?

Tags: 14.04, unity, notification, webapps, gmail

I'm trying to integrate gmail with my Ubuntu desktop, recently upgraded to version 14.04, but I don't remember if i have previously accepted to integrate gmail with the desktop. How can I check this? I am not seeing any notification of new emails or anything in the task-bar or notification area,so does this mean it is not set up, or it is not working, or it is not configured or whatever. Is there any unified configuration for the unity web apps?

Just want to **emphasize the last part of the question, regarding configuration of web apps**. Is it possible to configure the functionality of the unity web apps? I see that gmail is showing a mail-icon in the notification-area on incoming mail, when the gmail-webapp is running. So how can I configure web apps behavior in unity?

Answer (score 2):

If you choose **command-line** method than @SylvainPineau 's answer is ok.

Otherwise you can find-out (or launch) directly from **Dash** as following!

[image] 
For gmail notification:

[image]

---

For configuring manually unity-webapps, goto userscript `/usr/share/unity-webapps/userscripts/unity-webapps-gmail`. [more](https://askubuntu.com/questions/215047/can-i-configure-notification-period-of-webapps/215078#215078)

Comment: Thanks Pandya, the Dash-solution suggested by you and Sudheer is most appropriate, as I'm interested in using it, not just if it's installed or not. I'm surprised there is no mention of configuration options for webapps, so I guess they don't exist?

Comment: Hi, Pandya, none of the answers so far have addressed or even mentioned the configuration-issue, as I mentioned above. I've upvoted the answer that was working for me regarding if the gmail webapp was installed.

Comment: Pandya, when you edit a question: it's good practice to actually improve the question, not just make some random, possibly incorrect changes.

Answer (score 1):

If unity web app for gmail is installed then type gmail in dash it should show a mail icon open it, if not its not installed. To install you should open firefox then go to gmail then a pop up will come to install gmail web app select install wait for few seconds it will get installed.

To get mail notifications you should have gmail web apps application minimized or running. if it is closed you wont get any notifications regarding new mail arrivals.

Comment: OK, it seems it was installed. But do I really have to have it running to get email notifications? the only thig I get from having it installed is gmail in a separate browser-window?

Comment: Yes you can minimize it if new mail arrives it will show number on the icon.

Answer (score 1):

To check installed Unity webapps you can use the following command:

```
dpkg-query -W -f='${db:Status-Abbrev} ${binary:Package} ${Section}\n' unity-webapps-* | awk '{if ($1 == "ii" && $3 != "gnome") {print $2}}'
```

I use `awk` here to only keep installed packages and avoid listing the webapps service and common packages (which belong to the Gnome debian section).

Answer (score 1):

Run the below command on terminal to check if Unity webapps gmail is installed or not.

```
apt-cache policy unity-webapps-gmail | awk '/ Installed:/{ print $0}'
```

If the output shows `Installed: (none)` then it is not installed on your system or if it shows the output like this `Installed: 2.4.16` then it's installed on your's.